# Text Extraction from Images

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, text-mining, text-analytics-api

I did extraction of text from image. I got unstructured data after extracting text. I have to convert this to a structured form but I'm not able to do the so.

The unstructured data extracted from image in python:

```
EQUITY-LARGE CAP ©@ SBIMUTUAL FUND
A’ A PARTNER FOR LIFE
LSS LAST DIVIDENDS Ct EV a A)
i Option NAV @) Record Date Dividend (in /Unit) NAV (@)
BLUE CH | Pp FU N D Reg-Plan-Growth 34.9294 23-Sep-16 (Reg Plan) 1.00 18.5964
—————— a 23-Sep-16 (Dir Plan) 1.20 21.8569
= Reg-Plan-Dividend 19.8776 9 =
An Open-ended Growth Scheme = -Reg-Plan-Dividend 188776 TT a5 Reg Plan) 2.50 17.6880
Dir-Plan-Dividend 23.5613 17-Jul-15 (Dir Plan) 2.90 20.5395
. . ir a 21- Mar-14 (Reg Plan) 1.80 12.7618
Investment Objective Dir-Plan-Growth 36.2961
a. . a. Pursuant to payment of dividend, the NAV of Dividend Option of
To provide investors with opportunities scheme/plans would fall to the extent of payout and statutory levy, if
for long-term growth in capital through applicable.
anactive management of investments ina
diversified basket of equity stocks of
companies whose market capitalization
is at least equal to or more than the least PORTFOLIO
market capitalized stock of S&P BSE 100
face Stock Name (%) Of Total AUM Stock Name (%) Of Total AUM
. HDFC Bank Ltd. 8.29 Apollo Hospitals Enterprises Ltd. 1.04
Fund Details Larsen & Toubro Ltd. 4.46 Tata Motors Ltd. (Dvr-A-Ordy) 0.85
ITC Ltd. 4.07 Eicher Motors Ltd. 0.84
+ Type of Scheme UPL Ltd. 2.95 Shriram City Union Finance Ltd. 0.79
An Open - Ended Growth Scheme Infosys Ltd. 2.93 Divi's Laboratories Ltd. 0.73
Mahindra & Mahindra Ltd. 2.92 Pidilite Industries Ltd. 0.62
+ Date of Allotment: 14/02/2006 Nestle India Ltd. 2.90 Fag Bearings India Ltd. 0.62
. . Reliance Industries Ltd. 2.86 Sadbhav Engineering Ltd. 0.61
Reno AS ono /OG/2007 Indusind Bank Ltd. 2.68 Grasim Industries Ltd. 0.60
+ AAUM for the Month of June 2017 State Bank Of India 2.63 Petronet LNG Ltd. 0.60
214,204.29¢ Kotak Mahindra Bank Ltd. 2.57 Hudco Ltd. 0.58
, rores HCL Technologies Ltd. 2.50 Torrent Pharmaceuticals Ltd. 0.55
+» AUMas on June 30, 2017 Bharat Electronics Ltd. 2.48 Thermax Ltd. 0.52
% 14,292.59 Crores Cholamandalam Investment And Dr. Lal Path Labs Ltd. 0.49
: — - Finance Company Ltd. 2.36 Coal India Ltd. 0.44
+ Fund Manager: Ms. Sohini Andani Hero Motocorp Ltd. 2.16 Narayana Hrudayalaya Ltd. 0.41
Managing Since: Sep-2010 Hindustan Petroleum Corporation Ltd. 2.11 Britannia Industries Ltd. 0.40
i . Motherson Sumi Systems Ltd. 1.98 Tata Steel Ltd. 0.38
Total Experience: Over 22 years Maruti Suzuki India Ltd. 1.90 Procter & Gamble Hygiene And
+ Benchmark: S&P BSE 100 Index ICICI Bank Ltd. 1.88 Health Care Ltd. 0.38
— Sun Pharmaceuticals Industries Ltd. 1.66 SKF India Ltd. 0.35
+ Exit Load: HDFC Ltd. 1.66 ff Tata Motors Ltd. 0.26
For exit within 1 year from the date of Strides Shasun Ltd. 1.59 Equity Shares Total 90.22
allotment - 1%; For exit after 1 year Titan Company Ltd. 1.58 Motilal Oswal Securities Ltd
fi he d f n il Hindalco Industries Ltd. 1.57 CP Mat 28.07.2017. 0.42
rom the date of allotment - Ni Ultratech Cement Ltd. 1.52 [| Commercial Paper Total 0.42
+ Entry Load: N.A. Voltas Ltd. 1.48 HDFC Bank Ltd. 0.14
- - Mahindra & Mahindra Financial Services Ltd. 1.42 Fixed Deposits Total 0.14
+ Plans Available: Regular, Direct The Ramco Cements Ltd. 1.41 CBLO 8.24
. a ao PI Industries Ltd. 1.40 Cash & Other Receivables (4.29)
Options: Growth, Dividend Aurobindo Pharma Ltd. 1.39 Futures 4.72
+ SIP Indian Oil Corporation Ltd. 1.36 HDFC Ltd. 0.56
Weekly - Minimum & 1000 & in multiples The Federal Bank Ltd. 1.22 Warrants Total 0.56
LIC Housing Finance Ltd. 1.18 Grand Total 100.00
of = 1 thereafter for a minimum of 6 Shriram Transport Finance Company Ltd. 1.10
instalments.
Monthly - Minimum = 1000 & in
Eee ee aC PORTFOLIO CLASSIFICATION BY PORTFOLIO CLASSIFICATION BY
See ee eae Oe INDUSTRY ALLOCATION (%) ASSET ALLOCATION (%)
multiples of = 1 thereafter for minimum
one year. Financial Services 29.34
Quarterly - Minimum % 1500 & in Automobile 10.90 s.o6 172
multiples of = 1 thereafter for minimum ronsumer Goods 03
nergy :
one WEEN Construction 6.54 18.66
+ Minimum Investment Pharma 5.93 *
= 5000 & in multiples of = 1 IT 5.43
resi Fertilisers & Pesticides 4.35
. Additional Investment Industrial Manufacturing 3.97
< HOO © tho coawlittas Gtr Cement & Cement Products 3.53
Metals 2.39 71.55
Quantitative Data Healthcare Services 1.93
Chemicals 0.62
Standard Deviation® 112.21% Cash & Other Recivables -4.29 L c = Mia
mLarge Cap jidcap
Beta* :0.86 Futures 4.72
ae cBLO 8.24
Sharpe Ratio’ 0.76 Fixed Deposits 0.14 m Cash & Other Current Assets Futures
Portfolio Turnover* 11.03
*Source: CRISIL Fund Analyser Riskometor SBI Blue Chip Fund
“Portfolio Turnover = lower of total sale or one] > This product is suitable for investors who are seeking:
total purchase for the last 12 months L\E * Long term capital appreciation,
Fe on C aL a GCM cL OT LT Ss BAA Z*3\ * Investment in equity shares of companies whose market capitalization is at least equal to or more
Risk Free rate: FBIL Overnight Mibor rate Inve EE sical than the least market capitalized stock of S&P BSE 100 index to provide long term capital growth
(6.25% as on 30th June 2017) Basis for will best Moderately Highrisk | OPPOrtunities.
Ratio Calculation: eavcarsiMonthiy{Data ‘Alnvestors should consult their financial advisers if in doubt about whether the product is suitable for them.
```

The image:
[image]

Please help to convert this unstructured data to structure data. Any library or any function suggested?

Comment: How did you do that? Post the code and a sample image.

Comment: the image is there in the question. Please check it.

Comment: i had post the question. Kindly help me out with this. i also have the image in the question

Comment: can you tell us how did you do the extraction?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have certain parameters to split,

```
text=inp_text.split(".\n")## this will help to split where full stop and new line starts 
text= re.split('\s{4,}',inp_text) ## this will help to split where atleast 4 white spaces
```

Comment: Kindly have the image in the answer. and I need to do accordingly. Only the AUM section.